# Adding URL string to URL Array and then retrieving URL image Data for TableView

Tags: uitableview, for-loop, url, caching

Ok so I am following a tutorial on youtube b/c my ultimate goal is to use NSCache. I have this function called photoQuery(). PhotoQuery() looks up username in usernameArray. usernameArray has two usernames.
 I then run a URL look up to find the image and append the image to a UIImageArray called messageImageArray. For the two usernames in usernameArray... I get three images added to my imageArray.

The output shows an obvious error in my logic, but I do not understand:
The print(URL) should only print twice... but it prints three times
The print(URLArray.count) should only print twice... 1, then 2... however it prints 1, 2, 2...
The print(messageImageArray) should only prints two images... but it prints three
... From this the first url is being called twice to display the same image, meanwhile the second url is only called once. Can someone solve this?

```
func photoQuery () {
    for username in self.usernameArray {
        let photoQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserPhoto")
        photoQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)
        photoQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?,error: Error?) in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                if error == nil {
                let userImageFile = object["photo"] as? PFFileObject
                let urlString = userImageFile?.url as! String
                self.urlArray.append(urlString)
            }
        }
            for url in self.urlArray {
                print(self.urlArray.count)
            print(url)
            if let url = URL(string: url) {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
            if let imageData = data {
                self.messageImageArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData)!)
                print(self.messageImageArray)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it by combining the two functions:

Comment: let userImageFile = object["photo"] as? PFFileObject
                    let urlString = userImageFile?.url as! String
                    //self.urlArray.append(urlString)
                        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                            if let imageData = data {
                self.messageImageArray.append(UIImage(data:imageData)!)
                print(self.messageImageArray)